# Vuetify 3 Responsive Layous Not Adapting

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I've just started using Vuetify and am *extremely* confused about achieving a proper functioning responsive layout. I've just gotten confused by the lack of direction in the documentation.

I span up the default app as detailed in the Getting Started section of the docs. So that vanilla app was the starting point.

**Default.vue**

```xml
<template>
  <v-app id="app">
    <default-bar />
    <default-view />
    <default-footer />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

**View.vue**

```xml
<template>
  <v-main>
    <router-view />
  </v-main>
</template>
```

**Home.vue**

```xml
<v-container class="fill-height">
  <v-responsive class="align-center text-center fill-height">
    
    <v-sheet class="mx-auto pa-10 ma-10 rounded-shaped">
    ...
    <v-sheet>

  <v-responsive>
<v-container>
```

I've tried putting my content `v-sheet`s inside `v-cols`, such as `<v-col xs="12" sm="5" md="3">` but still no success.

It seems the content, such as the header set with `class="text-h2 mb-10"` is always pretty large and doesn't seem to be responding to breakpoints for small screens.

I'm just genuinely at a loss as to what the recommended approach to this is since the docs don't really seem to cover this angle, unless I've missed it.

Is the heirarchy of my `v-xxxx` components correct? If so, I was expecting elements like `text-hxxx` to also respond to breakpoints?

Any pointers to a simple approach to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you try to bind it? *Ex:* ( ```v-col class="gutter-row" :xs="12" :md="5" :lg="4" :xl="4">``` )

Comment: I have only just back onto the project. Will have a check of this and see how it pans out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`v-responsive` shouldn't be used there. I suppose what you intend to do, disregarding the router and different components, is this.

```html
<v-container class="fill-height">
  <v-row class="justify-center align-center">
    
    <v-col cols="12" md="5" lg="4">
      <v-sheet class="mx-auto pa-10 ma-10 rounded-shaped">
      ...
      <v-sheet>
    </v-col>

  </v-row>
<v-container>
```

This is explained in the `grids` section https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/